# How to connect tables

Tags: sqlite

Im stuck with my code. I want everything from my serviceticket table to be shown with CUSTID. I get an error "ambiguous column name: CUSTID"
Can anyone help me? I have tried everything

```
create table customers(CUSTID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    FIRSTNAME TEXT(50),
    LASTNAME TEXT (50),
    STREET TEXT(50),
    CITY TEXT(50),
    ZIP INT(4),
    PHONENUMBER INT(8),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(50)
);

create table serviceticket(SERVICETICKETID int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TICKETNUMBER INT,
    CUSTID int,
    DATE_RECIEVED text,
    EXPECTED_DELIEVERYDATe TEXT,
    COMMENTS TEXT,
    DATE_RETURNED TEXT
);

insert into customers (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STREET, CITY, ZIP, PHONENUMBER, EMAIL) 
  values ('Jørgen', 'Marven', 'Dræmmestad 22', 'Gjøvik', 6026,12837262, 'jørge@gmail.com');

insert into serviceticket(SERVICETICKETID, TICKETNUMBER,CUSTID, DATE_RECIEVED, EXPECTED_DELIEVERYDATE, COMMENTS, DATE_RETURNED)
  values (56, 133, NULL, NULL, '12/4/19', '22/4/19', 'Wants authenic parts', '22/4/19');


select SERVICETICKETID, TICKETNUMBER, CUSTID, DATE_RECIEVED, EXPECTED_DELIEVERYDATE, COMMENTS, DATE_RETURNED
from serviceticket, customers
where serviceticket.CUSTID = customers.CUSTID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `select SERVICETICKETID, TICKETNUMBER, CUSTID, ...` without specifying whether the `CUSTID` is from `serviceticket` or `customers`. Write

```
select SERVICETICKETID, TICKETNUMBER, customers.CUSTID, ...
```

and you should use the join syntax that is newer than the where syntax for joining tables. You can also use table aliases to make the query more readable

```
select
    S.SERVICETICKETID, S.TICKETNUMBER, C.CUSTID, S.DATE_RECIEVED, S.EXPECTED_DELIEVERYDATE,
    S.COMMENTS, S.DATE_RETURNED
from
    serviceticket S
    INNER JOIN customers C
        ON S.CUSTID = C.CUSTID
```

Comment: You specified `NULL` for `CUSTID` when inserting into `serviceticket`. You must use the  `CUSTID` from the corresponding customer. You can get it with `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` or `select seq from sqlite_sequence where name="customers"`